# Does removing redundant SCSS imports affect compile time?

Tags: css, import, sass, scss-mixins

Lets say I have a file `variables.scss` and `mixins.scss`

In my file `component.scss` I import both.

But `mixins.scss` itself, imports `variables.scss`.

Is this redundant? Does it matter? Does removing the `variables.scss` import in component file make any difference in compile time? Especially if I have many components that do this?

Comment: It makes no sense to import your variables.scss more than once, but I doubt it makes a difference to compile time as it is only where each variable is being applied that contributes to that I believe. Also, for your information scss is ditching the @ import which is used in css for @ forward and @ use
https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules